# Should I use "the John" or "the john" when referring to the slang phrase for toilet?

Tags: slang, capitalization, names, humor, eponyms

Should I capitalize the "j" in John when referring to a toilet as "the john." The same goes for lazy Susan and other words that are also names.

Comment: It's [six of one and half-a-dozen of the other.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=going+to+the+john%2Cgoing+to+the+John&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgoing%20to%20the%20john%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgoing%20to%20the%20John%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: ...or seven of one, baker's half-dozen of the other.  Generally, though "john" for "toilet" is generally *not* capitalized.  Similarly, the item called a "lazy susan" isn't capitalized either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since *the john* is not a proper noun, lower case is more useful for clarity. This way, you could avoid ambiguity in situations like...

> When **John** arrived at work, he headed straight for **the john**.

Comment: Right, and the Brits say loo and we all say head, if we are used to being on and around boats. And there's a famous joke: Rest room? Who's tired? Where's the can?

Comment: I once played the role in Michael Frayn's "Noises Off" of a geriatric burglar who kept eluding residents by posing as a plumber. It gave me a special appreciation for British potty language =)